# Fundamental group of 2 copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ glued along a common $\mathbb{R}P^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I was working on questions about computing fundamental groups from past qualifying exam papers and I wanted to know if I'm going about it correctly. The question reads

> Recall that the standard embedding of $\mathbb{R}P^1$ in $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is the image of the equator under the 2-fold cover $\pi : S^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ given by $\pi (x) = \pi (-x)$. Let $X$ be the union of two projective planes glued via the identity map of the standardly embedded $\mathbb{R}P^1$s. Compute the fundamental group of $X$.

My idea was to consider $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as an upper hemisphere with the boundary circle identified by the antipodal map. This boundary circle (when sent to the quotient) is $\mathbb{R}P^1$. Now instead of gluing after sending to the quotient, I thought of gluing before, so that effectively you take two hemispheres, glue them along the boundaries and apply the antipodal map to the boundary circle. Now, applying Seifert-van Kampen, I have one generator $x$ for one copy and another generator $y$ for the other copy, satisfying $x^2 = y^2 = e$. For the amalgamation, the inclusions of the generator of the intersection into either $\mathbb{R}P^2$ are $x^2$ and $y^2$ respectively, so the new relation is $x^2y^{-2} = e$ which is already true. So we get $\pi _1 (X) = \langle x, y | x^2 = y^2 = e \rangle$ which is just $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2$

Is this correct? Because this is also the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2$, so I'm kind of unsure.

Comment: I would draw a picture of $\Bbb RP^2$ and see how $\Bbb RP^1$ lives inside of it. The map $\pi_1(\Bbb RP^1) \to \pi_1(\Bbb RP^2)$ is surjective. To solve the problem at hand work out an explicit cell structure for your space and use the standard lemma on $\pi_1$ of CW-complexes or if you are going to use SVK make sure to work out all the open sets.

Comment: The standard CW structure on $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is a 0-cell $e^0$, a 1-cell $e^1$ whose boundary is glued to $e^0$, and a 2-cell $e^2$ whose boundary is attached by a degree 2 map to $e^1$. Now if I identify two of them along $e^1$, the CW structure on $X$ is the same 1-skeleton but now there are 2 $e^2$s attached via a degree 2 map. I don't think the additional 2-cell changes the homotopy type, because both are attached via a degree 2 map. So then is $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}_2 = \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)$?

Comment: The additional 2-cell definitely "changes the homotopy type", but it gives a redundant relation on the level of $\pi_1$. So if you write down a presentation from the lemma you will get $\pi_1(X) \cong \langle a | a^2, a^2 \rangle$ which is of course $\Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: Could you tell me what was wrong with my initial method with SVK? I know I didn't do it formally with open sets but what was wrong with the intuition?

Comment: The thing wrong is that you have the wrong map for the inclusion. The map $\pi_1(\Bbb RP^1) \to \pi_1(\Bbb RP^2)$ is surjective (and this is still true when you look at neighborhoods of both in $X$).

Comment: So if I were to use it correctly, I'd realize that the inclusion of the generator of $\mathbb{R}P^1$ into the $\mathbb{R}P^2$s is actually $g \mapsto x$ and $g \mapsto y$ so that the relation is $x=y$, and so $\pi_1 (X) = \langle x, y | x = y, x^2 = y^2 = e \rangle \cong \langle x | x^2 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_2$, right?

Comment: Yeah that's right.

Comment: Use the Van Kampen Theorem to get $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2\cup_{\mathbb{R}P^1}\mathbb{R}P^2)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.  When gluing, you need to keep in mind that the boundary circle has been quotiented out by the antipodal map.  This means that the intersection of the two copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is the boundary circle mod the antipodal identification, not the boundary circle itself.  In particular, the generator of the fundamental group of the intersection corresponds to just $x$ and $y$, not $x^2$ and $y^2$, since after quotienting by the antipodal map you only have to go around the circle halfway to get a loop.  So the amalgamation ends up identifying $x$ and $y$ in $\pi_1(X)$, so you get just $\mathbb{Z}_2$.